# How to cut white spaces above the image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I have a project with neural nets that work on images like this:

[image]

As you see, it have a blank space in the margin top. My question is if this space can interfere in the network results, and if yes, how can I cut only the blank space using python/openCV considering that the white space is not the same size and position in all images

Another example:

[image]

(Open the image to see the white space clearly)

Comment: Instead of cutting, can you simply fill in the missing information with background pixels?  Cutting the pixels, then warping the image so that it's the expected size for the network will skew them considerably which your network may not be trained on.  An alternative would be to present these images to your network and fold them into your training.  Therefore, we should fall back to the question is how are these white regions being generated?

Comment: I'm sorry about the ignorance, but you can exemplify how to fill the background?

Comment: If the object is far away from the border, simply replicate the pixels from the border to fill up the image.  If you are training an image classification pipeline, they should ideally ignore these border pixels now they are not completely white.  However, this doesn't answer the broad question of *how* these white regions are generated.  If we can understand how these are generated, it may be possible to provide an alternative to the other two approaches I was suggesting.  Please describe how the white regions are generated.

Comment: I have this images from a large dataset. I have the images already with it

Comment: If this is already provided to you, why don't you just supply these images to the network?  Remember that conv layers are just feature extractors so areas with uniform regions of colour get ignored.

Comment: You say that if I keep the white space, it does not interfere in my network results?

Comment: It shouldn't. Did you even try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to fill the space with black in Python/OpenCV.

Pad the image all around with 1 pixel wide border of white. Then floodfill the padded image from the top left corner (0,0) with black. Then remove the 1 pixel wide border. This assumes that you do not have any pure white pixels of real data at the sides of your original image.

Input 1:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('border_image1.jpeg')
#img = cv2.imread('border_image2.jpeg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# add 1 pixel white border all around
pad = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray, 1,1,1,1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=255)
h, w = pad.shape

# create zeros mask 2 pixels larger in each dimension
mask = np.zeros([h + 2, w + 2], np.uint8)

# floodfill outer white border with black
img_floodfill = cv2.floodFill(pad, mask, (0,0), 0, (5), (0), flags=8)[1]

# remove border
img_floodfill = img_floodfill[1:h-1, 1:w-1]

# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('border_image1_floodfilled.png',img_floodfill)
#cv2.imwrite('border_image2_floodfilled.png',img_floodfill)

# show the images
#cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("pad", pad)
cv2.imshow("img_floodfill", img_floodfill)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result 1:

[image]

The remaining whitish region along the diagonal edge is likely because the image posted was a JPG version of a PNG image. The JPG has lossy compression which causes these kinds of effects. Note that I used a 5 gray level lower difference to allow for some deviation of whitish value in that region from pure white. This reduced the extraneous white, but did not remove it completely. However, it may have changed a few whitish data pixels along the sides of the image. So you can put it back to 0, but will have more white remaining along that diagonal region.

Input 2:

[image]

Result 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to trim the image of all its background color in Python/OpenCV.

(I did not try to optimize or streamline the code. It is just a demonstration of the concept. For example, the computation of the 4 mean values could be made into a function def, since they all are the same lines of code repeated for each side. *If someone rewrites the code more efficiently or optimizes it, please repost so others can benefit.*)

Basically, one thresholds the image so that the background is black and the rest is white as a mask. (I used cv2.inRange() so that a color image could be used for the input.) Then one tests the mean of each outside 1 pixel thick side of the mask to see if it is not pure white (255) and which side has the lowest mean (darkest). If not pure white and the darkest side, then increment/decrement the value of the side coordinate (as if removing that row or column, but not actually doing it). Continue testing interior rows and columns from the sides inward until all rows and columns tested are pure white. This is somewhat like peeling an onion. Then get the final side coordinates and crop the image.

**First Image:**

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('border_image1.jpeg')
#img = cv2.imread('border_image2.jpeg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# threshold so border is black and rest is white (invert as needed)
lower = (254,254,254)
upper = (255,255,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
mask = 255 - mask


# define top and left starting coordinates and starting width and height
top = 0
left = 0
bottom = h
right = w

# compute the mean of each side of the image and its stop test
mean_top = np.mean( mask[top:top+1, left:right] )
mean_left = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, left:left+1] )
mean_bottom = np.mean( mask[bottom-1:bottom, left:right] )
mean_right = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, right-1:right] )

mean_minimum = min(mean_top, mean_left, mean_bottom, mean_right)

top_test = "stop" if (mean_top == 255) else "go"
left_test = "stop" if (mean_left == 255) else "go"
bottom_test = "stop" if (mean_bottom == 255) else "go"
right_test = "stop" if (mean_right == 255) else "go"
#print(top_test,left_test,bottom_test,right_test)

# iterate to compute new side coordinates if mean of given side is not 255 (all white) and it is the current darkest side
while top_test == "go" or left_test == "go" or right_test == "go" or bottom_test == "go":

    # top processing
    if top_test == "go":
        if mean_top != 255:
            if mean_top == mean_minimum:
                top += 1
                mean_top = np.mean( mask[top:top+1, left:right] )
                mean_left = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, left:left+1] )
                mean_bottom = np.mean( mask[bottom-1:bottom, left:right] )
                mean_right = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, right-1:right] )
                mean_minimum = min(mean_top, mean_left, mean_right, mean_bottom)
                #print("top",mean_top)
                continue
        else:
            top_test = "stop"   

    # left processing
    if left_test == "go":
        if mean_left != 255:
            if mean_left == mean_minimum:
                left += 1
                mean_top = np.mean( mask[top:top+1, left:right] )
                mean_left = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, left:left+1] )
                mean_bottom = np.mean( mask[bottom-1:bottom, left:right] )
                mean_right = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, right-1:right] )
                mean_minimum = min(mean_top, mean_left, mean_right, mean_bottom)
                #print("left",mean_left)
                continue
        else:
            left_test = "stop"  

    # bottom processing
    if bottom_test == "go":
        if mean_bottom != 255:
            if mean_bottom == mean_minimum:
                bottom -= 1
                mean_top = np.mean( mask[top:top+1, left:right] )
                mean_left = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, left:left+1] )
                mean_bottom = np.mean( mask[bottom-1:bottom, left:right] )
                mean_right = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, right-1:right] )
                mean_minimum = min(mean_top, mean_left, mean_right, mean_bottom)
                #print("bottom",mean_bottom)
                continue
        else:
            bottom_test = "stop"    

    # right processing
    if right_test == "go":
        if mean_right != 255:
            if mean_right == mean_minimum:
                right -= 1
                mean_top = np.mean( mask[top:top+1, left:right] )
                mean_left = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, left:left+1] )
                mean_bottom = np.mean( mask[bottom-1:bottom, left:right] )
                mean_right = np.mean( mask[top:bottom, right-1:right] )
                mean_minimum = min(mean_top, mean_left, mean_right, mean_bottom)
                #print("right",mean_right)
                continue
        else:
            right_test = "stop" 


# crop input
result = img[top:bottom, left:right]

# print crop values 
print("top: ",top)
print("bottom: ",bottom)
print("left: ",left)
print("right: ",right)
print("height:",result.shape[0])
print("width:",result.shape[1])

# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('border_image1_cropped.png',result)
#cv2.imwrite('border_image2_cropped.png',result)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("cropped", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Cropped image:

[image]

Crop coordinates:

```
top:  132
bottom:  512
left:  3
right:  507
height: 380
width: 504
```

**Second Image:**

[image]

Cropped Image:

[image]

Crop Coordinates:

```
top:  0
bottom:  420
left:  0
right:  512
height: 420
width: 512
```