# imaginary Bounding Box

Tags: python, opencv, gis, object-detection, contour

Let's say I have a picture like this (Image 1). Isohypses are drawn so that they form a rectangle, which should correspond to the edge of a map. I want to detect that rectangle.

[image: Image 1]

In red, I drew the rectangle I would like to get (Image 2).

[image: Image 2]

P.S.
Topographic maps are mostly in the shape of isosceles trapezoids that are very similar to rectangles, so the additional question is how to get to a shape that is not a classic rectangle but a trapezoid.

I tried to get some results via contour approximation in OpenCV in Python, but it didn't work. Please suggest a solution in Python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use Python Wand, which used images magick and use the equivalent of -trim. -trim removes all constant color surrounding any figure. So it will remove your outer white and stop at the ends/edges of your contours (any black).

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434997/how-to-cut-white-spaces-above-the-image/62437669#62437669

Answer (score 3):

We may find the minimum and maximum X, Y coordinates of all the black pixels.
Minimum x and minimum y is the top left corner.
Maximum x and maximum y is the top right corner.

We may use the following stages (using OpenCV and NumPy):

- Convert to grayscale and Apply automatic thresholding (and invert polarity):

  ```
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  #  Convert to grayscale

   ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  # Apply automatic thresholding (and invert polarity).
  ```
- Optionally use opening morphological operation for removing the right side of the cross
- Find indices of white pixels in thresh (black pixels in the original image).

  ```
   y_idx, x_idx = thresh.nonzero()
  ```
- Find the minimum X index, minimum Y index, maximum X index, maximum Y index.

  ```
   x0 = x_idx.min()
   y0 = y_idx.min()
   x1 = x_idx.max()
   y1 = y_idx.max()
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('map.jpg')  # Read input image

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  #  Convert to grayscale

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  # Apply automatic thresholding (and invert polarity).

thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((2, 1), np.uint8))  # Use opening morphological operation for removing the right side of the cross

# Find indices of white pixels in thresh (black pixels in the original image).
y_idx, x_idx = thresh.nonzero()

# Find the minimum X index, minimum Y index, maximum X index, maximum Y index.
x0 = x_idx.min()
y0 = y_idx.min()
x1 = x_idx.max()
y1 = y_idx.max()

roi = img[y0:y1+1, x0:x1+1, :].copy()  # Crop the relevant ROI.

cv2.rectangle(img, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (0, 0, 255), 3)  # Draw red rectangle.



# Show output for testing
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imwrite('img.png', img)  # Save image for testing
```

---

Output `img`:
[image]