# Real-time Document Detection when Background Color is Similar

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract the corner points of the document to warp the image. I could successfully done with backgrounds that has high contrast. However, when the background color is similar to the document, it failed. I have even tried using LAB space to segment the document, it was successful on the image, but not in the real-time feed. Could anyone help on this problem?

```
        import cv2

        frame = np.asarray(image)
        if(image.mode == 'RGB'):
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        frame_copy = frame.copy()
        scale_percent = 100
        if frame.shape[0] * frame.shape[1] >= 2000 * 2000:
            scale_percent = 30
        
        width = int(frame.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        height = int(frame.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        dim = (width, height)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        thres1 = 75
        thres2 = 200

        
        kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
        morph = cv2.morphologyEx(frame, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations= 3)
        lab = cv2.cvtColor(morph, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

        l, aa, bb = cv2.split(lab)


        threshold = cv2.threshold(bb, thres1, thres2, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

[Document with Similar Background Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yLou.jpg)

I have tried HSV, LAB color spaces, and some other methods.
Please help me to do segmentation when background color is similar to document in real-time scanning.

Comment: You will likely need to use AI.  See http://remove.bg. Or try something like that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446941/imaginative-bounding-box/76448298#76448298